pip install ultralytics on raspberrypi 3
I am working on an AI fire detection system using YOLOv8 and python, the system works perfectly on my laptop but on my raspberry pi, I am facing many problems. pip install is not working, I am getting "externally-managed-environment".
What shall I do? I tried using a virtual environment using "venv" but when I tried to run the code, I still got an error "no module named ultralytics" even though on the terminal I tried reinstalling it and I got "ultralytics already seems to be installed".

Have you followed these instructions from Ultralytics? https://docs.ultralytics.com/guides/raspberry-pi/?h=raspberry

Here is link: https://docs.ultralytics.com/guides/raspberry-pi/#start-without-docker  and for RPi-3: https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1259133/ultrasoftware-on-raspberry-pi-3

I just followed the instructions step by step but when I got to "pip3 install -r requirements.text" I got the same error again "this environmont is extrenally managed"

"but when I tried to run the code, I still got an error "no module named ultralytics"" - this is because you have to use the virtual environment where you installed the package, to run the code.
